# spark sql count(*) query store result

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hello I use Spark with Python,  I performed a basic count(*) query on a dataframe as follow

```
myquery = sqlContext.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM myDF")
```

Result is

```
+--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
|    3469|
+--------+
```

How can I save this value in order to perform futher operation.

For instance divide  3469 by 24  [whatever 24 means...]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given that your query returns `dataframe` as

```
+-----+
|count|
+-----+
|3469 |
+-----+
```

You need to get the first (and only) row, and then its (only) field 'count'

```
count = dataframe.first()['count']
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for the answer. It says AttributeError: getLong
. I think the getLong does not work

Comment: count = dataframe.first()['count'] may be better

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution. Actualy I think it's the best so far. You may add it as a single answer and I will vote for it. Regards

Comment: had to use this: dataframe.first()[0]

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> myquery = sqlContext.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM myDF").collect()[0][0]
>>> myquery
3469
```

This would get you only the count. Later type of `myquery` can be converted and used within successive queries e.g. if you want to show the entire row in the output.

This works in pyspark sql.
**Caution:** This would dump the entire row on the screen.

```
>>> sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM myDF").show(myquery,False)
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that you have `dataframe` as

```
+-----+
|count|
+-----+
|3469 |
+-----+
```

You can perform mathematical operation on columns and create new columns or overwrite on the same using `.withColumn` api

```
df.withColumn('devided', df.count/24).show(false)
```

You should get

```
+-----+------------------+
|count|devided           |
+-----+------------------+
|3469 |144.54166666666666|
+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: Hello Ramesh tanks a lot for the answer. But what about if I have 2 different sql query that give a unique value (count). In that case how to addition both values? My idea was rather to put the count value in a traditional python variable then performing some arithmetics (+ - * /) in python itself...

Comment: please update your question with as much detail as you can :)

Comment: Hello actually I have solve that question by transforming the count output with .toPandas() function. Then I simply use pandas to perform whatever operaiton. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Given that your query returns dataframe as

```
dataFrame.collect()(0).getLong(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to alias the count into another name and use it as follows:

```
        countvar = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM 
myDF""").first()["cnt"]
        print(countvar/24)
    
        countvar = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT count(*) as nullcnt FROM 
    myDF where id is null""").first()["nullcnt"]
        print(100*(nullcount/countvar))
    
        countvar = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT  count(distinct(id)) as idcnt 
FROM myDF """).first()["idcnt"]
        print(idcnt))
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit of explanation here?

Answer (score -4):

Just using count method on the dataframe will return an int to your spark driver

```
row_count = df.count()
whatever = row_count / 24
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more explicit. Sometimes I have complex count queries that use where statement. In that case I assume .count() can't help.

Comment: You could also use the where method but that implies some rewrite of the SQL query. If you want to avoid that suggest variant on Arthur's solution to get the first row and column returned `sqlContext.sql('select count(*) from myDF <where clause>').first()[0]`